# How to mathematically write functions on the surface of a sphere?

Tags: geometry

In spherical coordinates, you can have functions like in polar coordinates (r is a function of theta), where rho is a function of theta and phi.

But when talking strictly about the surface of a sphere, rho equals the radius of the sphere. How would you go about describing a function that lies on the surface of a sphere? Could you do it in terms of theta and phi?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A function whose domain is containes on the surface of the sphere can rewritten as a function of just $\theta$ and $\phi$, since the coordinates of any point on the sphere can be written as a function of only $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: What about a function whose range is on the surface of a sphere?

Comment: $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb S^2$, $f(x) = (\theta(x),\phi(x))$ where $X$ is the domain of the function (can be anything!), and $\theta:X \rightarrow [0,2\pi)$ and $\phi:X \rightarrow [0,2\pi)$ are functions.

Comment: You  are fixing  rho and by that you get the sphere defined. On it the function is drawn. You could view it as a similar case of defining ta line in 3D as the intersection of two palnes.